# Como agregar eventos onClick || addEventListener a una etiqueta template y un fragment JS

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, template, fragment

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema, he creado una etiqueta html template:

```
<template id="template-card">
    <div id="destino1" class="destinos" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="card card-destiny overflow-hidden shadow">
        <span data-action="left" class="cardArrow cardArrowLeft"><</span>
        <img class="card-img-top imgDestino" src="" alt="" />
        <span data-action="right" class="cardArrow cardArrowRight">></span>
        <div class="card-body py-4 px-3">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between mb-3">
            <h4 class="text-secondary fw-medium">
              <a class="link-900 text-decoration-none stretched-link card-title fw-bold" href="#contacto"></a>
            </h4>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between mb-3"></div>
            <h4 class="text-secondary fw-medium">
              <a class="link-900 text-decoration-none stretched-link card-title-locations locationCard fs-1" href="#contacto"></a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-column  card-date">
            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center mb-3"> 
          <a
            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg me-md-4 mb-3 mb-md-0 border-0 primary-btn-shadow bg-lightbrown" href="#contacto"
            role="button">¡Quiero este viaje!
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

La cual esta hecha un fragment con javascript para clonarse, con el siguiente codigo:

```
const destinosDiv = document.querySelector('#destinosContainer');
const templateCard = document.getElementById('template-card').content;
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const pintarCardsDestinos = destinos => {

    let destinoLength = destinos.length
    destinos.map(destino => {
        templateCard.querySelector('.card-img-top').src = destino.image;
        templateCard.querySelector('.card-img-top').alt = destino.title;
        templateCard.querySelector('.card-title').textContent = destino.title;
        templateCard.querySelector('.card-title-locations').textContent = destino.locations;
        const divDateTravel = templateCard.querySelector('.card-date');
        divDateTravel.textContent = '';
        destino.travel_date.map(date => {
            const spanDateTravel = document.createElement('span');
            spanDateTravel.classList.add('fs-0', 'fw-medium');
            spanDateTravel.textContent = `${date}`;
            divDateTravel.append(spanDateTravel);
        })


        const clone = templateCard.cloneNode(true)
        fragment.appendChild(clone)
    });
```

Quiero agregarle un evento a los spans 'cardArrow', intente con addEventListener pero no me funciona el click, no lo reconoce.
Lo que intento lograr es un slider basico
Mi solucion fue:

```
let contador = 0;
    templateCard.querySelector('.card-img-top').src = destino.image[contador];
    templateCard.querySelector('.card-img-top').alt = destino.title;

    templateCard.querySelector('.cardArrowLeft').addEventListener('click', () => {
        contador--;
        if(contador < 0) { contador = destino.image.length - 1 };
        templateCard.querySelector('.card-img-top').src = destino.image[contador];
    })

    templateCard.querySelector('.cardArrowRight').addEventListener('click', () => {
        contador++;
        if(contador > destino.image.length) { contador = 0 };
        templateCard.querySelector('.card-img-top').src = destino.image[contador];
    })
```

Algunos detalles que pude obtener son que al hacer un template, estos no estan disponibles para manipular directamente como cualquier otra etiqueta del DOM, sin embargo intentaban hacer algo con el atributo data. Sin embargo no encuentro soluciones para esto.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar un evento `onclick` en los `span` del HTML para llamar una función en la que podrás agregar la funcionalidad que necesitas, quedaría así en el HTML:

```
<span data-action="left" class="cardArrow cardArrowLeft" onclick="cardArrowLeft()"><</span>
<span data-action="right" class="cardArrow cardArrowRight" onclick="cardArrowRight()">></span>
```

Y en el JavaScript solo debes crear las funciones y colocar el código que quieres que se ejecute al presionar cada botón

```js
function cardArrowLeft() {
  // Insertar código
}

function cardArrowRight() {
  // Insertar código
}
```